# Java email listener

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I came across the IdleManager class and the watch method, which keeps the imap folder open and is in theory watching for new messages, but how do I get it to output or notify when a new email arrives?

The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    IMAPFolder folder = null;
    Store store = null;
    String subject = null;
    Flag flag = null;

    try 
    {
      Properties props = System.getProperties();
      props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
      props.setProperty("mail.imaps.usesocketchannels", "true");

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

      ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
      final IdleManager idleManager = new IdleManager(session, es);

      store = session.getStore("imaps");
      store.connect("<mail>.com","<username>", "<password>");

      folder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX"); 


      if(!folder.isOpen())
      folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

      folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {
          public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
              Folder folder = (Folder)ev.getSource();
              Message[] msgs = ev.getMessages();
              System.out.println("Folder: " + folder +
                  " got " + msgs.length + " new messages");
              try {
                  // process new messages
                  idleManager.watch(folder); // keep watching for new messages
              } catch (MessagingException mex) {
                  // handle exception related to the Folder
              }
          }
      });
      idleManager.watch(folder);


      Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
      System.out.println("No of Messages : " + folder.getMessageCount());
      System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());
      System.out.println(messages.length);


      for (int i=0; i < messages.length;i++) 
      {

        System.out.println("*****************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("MESSAGE " + (i + 1) + ":");
        Message msg =  messages[i];

        subject = msg.getSubject();

        System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
        System.out.println("From: " + msg.getFrom()[0]);
       System.out.println("To: "+msg.getAllRecipients()[0]);

      }
    }
    finally 
    {
      if (folder != null && folder.isOpen()) { folder.close(true); }
      if (store != null) { store.close(); }
    }

}
```

This code only gets and outputs the messages that were already in the folder, but it doesn't output new incoming emails.

How do I get it to output or notify new incoming emails?

Comment: You might need to open the folder READ_WRITE.  If that doesn't help, what server are you using?  Can you post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug)?  Make sure you're using at least JavaMail 1.6.0.

Comment: I changed it to READ_WRITE and it seems to work now, so thank you very much!

Comment: @BillShannon Now I receive the notification successfuly. But I can't print the last message. I tried like this, just after printing the notification:

`Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
System.out.println(messages[messages.length].toString());`

It doesn't print the last message.

Comment: @BillShannon if i try like `messages[0].getContent()` i get javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@7fb5b79c in the console

Comment: See the [msgshow.java](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java) sample program for examples of how to access the content of a message.

Comment: @BillShannon That READ_WRITE suggestion is a strange intuition. What gave you that idea? Is this common?

Comment: @arnt I don't know how common it is but I've run into it before, and I don't remember where.

Comment: @F_Bass don't you get "javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.io.IOException: Connection dropped by server?" exception after 30mins of idle time or so ?

Comment: @BillShannon how to make above code work if we get "javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.io.IOException: Connection dropped by server?" exception after 30mins of idle time or so ? Can you please let me know what code should be added ?