# JavaMail email listner isn't showing new Emails

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I've used below code which should ideally keep listening to new incoming emails.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    IMAPFolder folder = null;
    Store store = null;
    String subject = null;
    Flag flag = null;

    try 
    {
      Properties props = System.getProperties();
      props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
      props.setProperty("mail.imaps.usesocketchannels", "true");

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

      ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
      final IdleManager idleManager = new IdleManager(session, es);

      store = session.getStore("imaps");
      store.connect("<mail>.com","<username>", "<password>");

      folder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX"); 


      //if(!folder.isOpen())
      folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

      folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {
          public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
              Folder folder = (Folder)ev.getSource();
              Message[] msgs = ev.getMessages();
              System.out.println("Folder: " + folder +
                  " got " + msgs.length + " new messages");
              try {
                  // process new messages
                  idleManager.watch(folder); // keep watching for new messages
              } catch (MessagingException mex) {
                  // handle exception related to the Folder
              }
          }
      });
      idleManager.watch(folder);

      Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
      System.out.println("No of Messages : " + folder.getMessageCount());
      System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());
      System.out.println(messages.length);

    }
    finally 
    {
      if (folder != null && folder.isOpen()) { folder.close(true); }
      if (store != null) { store.close(); }
    }
}
```

source : [Java email listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60093386/java-email-listener) However `System.out.println("Folder: " + folder +" got " + msgs.length + " new messages");` isn't getting printed on arrival of new messages. Please find the debug log below :

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager select starting
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "abc.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=abc.com, user=username, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
A3 SELECT INBOX
* 771 EXISTS
* 1 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
* OK [UNSEEN 2] Is the first unseen message
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 2278797] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 783] The next unique identifier value
A3 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager watching imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX
A4 IDLE
+ IDLE accepted, awaiting DONE command.
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: set to IDLE
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: return true
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager.watch startIdle succeeded for imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 0 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
No of Messages : 771
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: request IdleManager to abort
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[main,5,main]
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 0 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager aborting IDLE for folder: imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX
DONE
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 1 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected folder: imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX
A4 OK IDLE completed.
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: set to RUNNING
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait done, idleState 0: Thread[main,5,main]
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager done watching folder imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
A5 SEARCH UNSEEN ALL
* SEARCH 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 100 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 189 190 191 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 205 206 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 219 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 430 431 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480 481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 522 523 524 526 527 528 529 530 531 532 533 534 535 536 537 538 539 540 541 542 543 544 545 546 547 548 549 550 551 552 553 554 555 556 557 558 559 560 561 562 563 564 565 566 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 580 581 582 583 584 585 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593 594 595 596 597 598 599 600 601 602 603 604 605 606 607 608 609 610 611 612 613 614 615 616 617 618 619 620 621 622 623 624 625 626 627 628 629 630 631 632 633 634 635 636 637 638 639 640 641 642 643 644 645 646 647 648 649 650 651 652 653 654 655 656 657 658 659 660 661 662 663 664 665 666 667 668 669 670 671 672 673 674 675 676 677 678 679 680 681 682 683 684 685 686 687 688 689 690 691 692 693 694 695 696 697 698 699 700 701 702 703 704 705 706 707 708 709 710 711 712 713 714 715 716 717 718 719 720 721 722 723 724 725 726 727 728 729 730 731 732 733 734 735 736 737 738 739 740 741 742 743 744 745 746 747 748 749 750 751 752 753 754 755 756 757 758 759 760 761 762 763 764 765 768 769 770 771
A5 OK SEARCH completed.
No of Unread Messages : 739
771
A6 CLOSE
A6 OK CLOSE completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup, force false
A7 LOGOUT
* BYE Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 IMAP4 server signing off.
A7 OK LOGOUT completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup done
```

As I could see  `* BYE Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 IMAP4 server signing off. A7 OK LOGOUT completed.` in the debug logs, I commented below code.

```
if (folder != null && folder.isOpen()) { folder.close(true); }
if (store != null) { store.close(); }
```

Still didn't get notified of new messages. Please find the debug logs below

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager select starting
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "abc.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=abc.com, user=username, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
A3 SELECT INBOX
* 771 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
* OK [UNSEEN 2] Is the first unseen message
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 2278797] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 783] The next unique identifier value
A3 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager watching imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX
A4 IDLE
+ IDLE accepted, awaiting DONE command.
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: set to IDLE
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: return true
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager.watch startIdle succeeded for imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 0 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
No of Messages : 771
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: request IdleManager to abort
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[main,5,main]
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 0 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager aborting IDLE for folder: imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX
DONE
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 1 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected folder: imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX
A4 OK IDLE completed.
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: set to RUNNING
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait done, idleState 0: Thread[main,5,main]
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager done watching folder imaps://username@abc.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
A5 SEARCH UNSEEN ALL
* SEARCH 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 100 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 189 190 191 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 205 206 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 219 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 430 431 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480 481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 522 523 524 526 527 528 529 530 531 532 533 534 535 536 537 538 539 540 541 542 543 544 545 546 547 548 549 550 551 552 553 554 555 556 557 558 559 560 561 562 563 564 565 566 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 580 581 582 583 584 585 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593 594 595 596 597 598 599 600 601 602 603 604 605 606 607 608 609 610 611 612 613 614 615 616 617 618 619 620 621 622 623 624 625 626 627 628 629 630 631 632 633 634 635 636 637 638 639 640 641 642 643 644 645 646 647 648 649 650 651 652 653 654 655 656 657 658 659 660 661 662 663 664 665 666 667 668 669 670 671 672 673 674 675 676 677 678 679 680 681 682 683 684 685 686 687 688 689 690 691 692 693 694 695 696 697 698 699 700 701 702 703 704 705 706 707 708 709 710 711 712 713 714 715 716 717 718 719 720 721 722 723 724 725 726 727 728 729 730 731 732 733 734 735 736 737 738 739 740 741 742 743 744 745 746 747 748 749 750 751 752 753 754 755 756 757 758 759 760 761 762 763 764 765 768 769 770 771
A5 OK SEARCH completed.
No of Unread Messages : 739
771
```

Any idea why new emails aren't being received ?

Comment: @Bill Shannon any idea on this?

Comment: Looks like you’re calling commands *after* you add it to the IDLE listener.  IDLE has to be cancelled to do commands.  Do your commands, then add the idle listener.

Comment: @Max thank you :) Adding idleManager.watch(folder); at the end just before finally block worked ! However after some time (more than 30 mins I guess) got javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.io.IOException: Connection dropped by server . how to make it work ?

Comment: I don't see anything in the IdleManager documentation indicating that it ever times out.  IDLE times out on most servers at 30 minutes, so needs to be periodically cancelled and renewed.  Also be sure to gracefully handle socket closures anyway, they happen even if you do everything right.  Put your entire application in a re-connect loop.

Comment: @Max sorry i didn't understand " IDLE times out on most servers at 30 minutes, so needs to be periodically cancelled and renewed." How to do it ?